# How to stop the service runs a SyncAdapter

Tags: android, service, android-syncadapter

I am working on a SyncAdapter by following the document:

http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html

The SyncAdapter is started with a service, the configuration is like this:

```
<service
            android:name="com.example.android.datasync.SyncService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":sync">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
    </service>
```

Here is the code of my service:

```
 public class SyncService extends Service {

  private static VmosoEventSyncAdapter sSyncAdapter;

  private static final Object sSyncAdatperLock = new Object();

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    synchronized (sSyncAdatperLock) {
      if (null == sSyncAdapter) {
        sSyncAdapter = new VmosoEventSyncAdapter(getApplicationContext(), true);
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // Toast.makeText(this, "Start performing events sync... this will be done in about 1 minute.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return sSyncAdapter.getSyncAdapterBinder();
  }

}
```

In my app, when user logs in, the sync adapter will start work (the client is the Calendar app, this SyncAdapter is to sync events between Calendar app and server).

When user logs off I want to stop the sync adapter, but I don't know how to stop this SyncAdapter and the ":sync" service, I tried to use `stopService(intent)`, but it doesn't work, I know this type service should be a bound service, `stopService` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This may be not an answer, but I'd like to share the workaround.

I removed the android:process=":sync" from the service configuration. In this way there will not be another process. And I removed the related account when user logs off, so the sync adapter won't work any longer until user logs in again.